# Add javascript to login page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

so i've this piece of code 
which is a login form

```
              <div class="form-group clearfix">
              <label for="inputPassword"><?php echo $CORE->_e(array('account','10')); ?></label>
              <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="form-control">                  
              </div>
            </div>

            <?php do_action('login_form'); ?>

            <hr />
```

which is good,

i want to add this script to it

```
function login_head() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}


function login_footer() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            var inserted = false;
            $('#login_error').on('click', '.sms-code-field', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();

                if(!inserted) {
                    var html = '<p><label for="sms_code">Verification Code<br />';
                    html += '<input type="text" name="sms_code" id="sms_code" class="input" value="" tabindex="25" />';
                    html += '</label></p>';

                    $('p.forgetmenot').before(html);
                    inserted = true;
                }
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

this script normally if used with the default themes 
when clicking on  "You are not verified yet, Please enter the verification code. Click here to enter verification code"

```
                    $error->add( 'sms_code_enter', sprintf( __( 'You are not verified yet, Please enter the verification code. <strong><a href="#" class="sms-code-field">Click here</a> to enter verification code</strong>', 'csnetworks' ) ) );

                    return $error;
                }
```

a new box with Verification Code header appears on the login page.

the problem is with the default login form from wordpress, there is that box that appears when clicking on You are not verified yet, but with the custom login form the box doesn't appear

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: nobody's gonna read that, keep code snippets smaller and to the point

Comment: ok cutted the code to the minimum

Comment: so, as APAD1 already asked... what is the problem? You're just stating what happens, but not what you expect it to happen (assuming that's different from what IS happening of course)

Comment: the problem is with the default login form from wordpress, there is that box that appears when clicking on You are not verified yet, but with the custom login form the box doesn't appear

Comment: Your onclick function is listening for an HTMLelement with the id '#login_error' and class '.sms-code-field' to be clicked but I don't see such an element in the html code you included.